# iBooks author customize template: change section's title color

Tags: mac, book, ibooks-author

I'm trying to build an iBook with iBooks Author on my Mac customizing the "Contemporary" template.
The point is when I switch the view mode from landscape to portrait Tte section title color is red but I want it to be green! Since I can edit the section title in landscape mode I can't understand why I'm not able to edit its color in here..

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have a related problem... I can't change the section title unless I'm in landscape mode.  Google turned up your question, which led me to discover that I could change it by switching to landscape mode.  Apparently, the portrait/landscape indicator just shows you approximately how your book will look on an iPad in the two orientations; it isn't a preferred orientation (although you can lock out portrait mode).  I think that in the current version, there are bugs in the portrait viewer, since several things are messed up when you change to that.  I'm going to go open a bug report with Apple.

Comment: yeah..write back for updates!